# How to check if object inherits from a generic base class without knowing type of typeparam

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, reflection, type-conversion

I have the following construct for classes:

```
public class Request : BaseRequest, IRequestFromResponse
{
}
```

which defines a `Request`-object to be posted via html form.

The `Model`, where the `Request` lives in build up like:

```
public class Response : BaseRequestWrapperResponse<Request>
{
}
```

while the BaseWrapper is build:

```
public abstract class BaseRequestWrapperResponse<TRequest> where TRequest : IRequestFromResponse
{
    public TRequest Request { get; set; }
}
```

`IRequestFromResponse` is just an empty marker-interface.

I try to cast the object at runtime, so I have access to the `Request`-property of `BaseRequestWrapperResponse`.

All I have so far is:

```
var model = ((ViewContext) context).ViewData.Model;

if (model.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof (BaseRequestWrapperResponse<IRequestFromResponse>)))
// if (model.GetType().BaseClass.IsAssignableFrom(typeof (BaseRequestWrapperResponse<IRequestFromResponse>)))
// if (model.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof (BaseRequestWrapperResponse<>)))
// if (model.GetType().BaseClass.IsAssignableFrom(typeof (BaseRequestWrapperResponse<>)))
{
    model = ((BaseRequestWrapperResponse<IRequestFromResponse>) model).Request;
}
```

I'm not able to get a check which indicates that `model` is some sort of `BaseRequestWrapperResponse`. The cast would then be my next problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding a non generic `BaseRequestWrapperResponse` class.

```
public abstract class BaseRequestWrapperResponse 
{
    public IRequestFromResponse Request { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseRequestWrapperResponse<TRequest> : BaseRequestWrapperResponse where TRequest : IRequestFromResponse
{
    public new TRequest Request
    {
        get{ return (TRequest)base.Request; }
        set{ base.Request = value; }
    }
}
```

Then just:

```
model = ((BaseRequestWrapperResponse) model).Request;
```

Answer (score 0):

This won’t work because the only types that the model is of is `Response` and `BaseRequestWrapperResponse<Request>`.

You have to understand that generic types are *concrete types* as soon as you put the type argument in. So since `Request` inherits from `BaseRequestWrapperResponse<Request>`, that `BaseRequestWrapperResponse<Request>` is an actual type that has no inheritance relationship to `BaseRequestWrapperResponse<TRequest>`. It’s just kind-of a copy with the type argument placed it.

You could see generic types more as *templates* for the actual types that are created when you put a generic type in. So when you used `BaseRequestWrapperResponse<Request>` you actually defined the following type:

```
public abstract class BaseRequestWrapperResponse_Request
{
    public Request Request { get; set; }
}
```

And there is no relationship to the generic type, and the information about its generic type argument.

If you want to access the `Request` object, you should add it to a common interface, e.g. `IResponse`, which your abstract generic type then implements:

```
public interface IResponse
{
    IRequestFromResponse Request { get; set; }
}
```

That will at least allow you to access the request object—although you may still have to cast it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var model = ((ViewContext) context).ViewData.Model;
var modelType = model.GetType();

if (modelType .GetGenericArguments()[0] == typeof (Request)) 
&& 
modelType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(BaseRequestWrapperResponse<>)) 
{
    model = ((BaseRequestWrapperResponse<Request>) model).Request;
}
```

Note that BaseRequestWrapperResponse does not inherit from BaseRequestWrapperResponse even if Request inherits from IRequestFromResponse, therefore you cannot do:

```
if (modelType .GetGenericArguments()[0].IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IRequestFromResponse)) && 
    modelType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(BaseRequestWrapperResponse<>)) 
    {
        model = ((BaseRequestWrapperResponse<IRequestFromResponse>) model).Request;
    }
```

if model's generic is actually BaseRequestWrapperResponse